# Is there a way to format the way regions collapse in VSCode/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to format the way regions collapse in vs code?

Currently, `PowerShell 5.1` collapse code looks the following:

```
#region Options
#endregion Options
```

Desired behavior

```
#region Options...
```

Comment: I get the latter. What language is it?

Comment: related: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding

Comment: The language is PowerShell

Comment: I get the latter as well for PowerShell. Have you set any settings that affect folding such as the default folding provider?

Comment: @user, you were correct I had a fold setting checked that said to include the last line for the fold. If you submit as answer I'll give you credit. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see such a setting... Is it coming from an extension? When you hover over the name of the setting in the settings editor, what's the ID in the hover tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PowerShell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) extension provides a setting to control that, and it's enabled by default:

```
"powershell.codeFolding.showLastLine": true
```

> Shows the last line of a folded section similar to the default VS Code
> folding style. When disabled, the entire folded region is hidden.